# What is lookup tables in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2003

I have the below entry when I go to the Insert > Name > Define name

='Lookup Tables'!$I$29:$I$65

What does it mean?

Comment: im assuming it refers to column I row's number 29-65, but of what I am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

It is called a named Range.  The name of which can be found in the Insert>Name>Define Dialog.

Lookup Tables is the name of a Sheet.  The Range on that sheet is I29-I65.

This construct can be used, for example, when reading an Excel spreadsheet using ADO.  You would reference the range in the SQL select statement "Select * from NamedRange.

Comment: sheet means workbook?


there are so many tabs (workbooks) in my excel ,,, which workbook i have to check?

Comment: To add to this, the $ symbol by the letter and the numbers ensure that if you copy the formual that it does not iterate the columns or row numbers.

Comment: i couldnt see any data in the range that you specified ... !!

Comment: A workbook is the equivalent of a file. Each tab is a worksheet within the workbook.

Comment: The data is on the Sheet (tab) named 'Lookup Tables'.

Answer (score -1):

> You can place a “lookup table” on a
>   worksheet and Excel can retrieve data
>   from it from a location on the same
>   worksheet, or in the same workbook, or
>   even from another workbook.
>
> This means, for example, that lookup
>   functions on an invoice worksheet can
>   handle the details of putting the unit
>   price in the right place. When prices
>   change, they only need to be changed
>   in the lookup table, not in every
>   individual invoice that is written.

[http://www.glencoe.com/ps/computered/pas/article.php4?articleId=41](http://www.glencoe.com/ps/computered/pas/article.php4?articleId=411)1